# Alternative word delimiter than underscore (_) for PostgreSQL objects (fields, tables, etc.) which doesn't require me to use quotes ("") to query?

Tags: postgresql, delimiter

Is there any alternative word delimiter other than underscore (_) for PostgreSQL objects (fields, tables, etc.) which doesn't require me to use quotes ("") to query?

The special delimiter will be used to separate identically named field names based on their source table. I don't want to use schemas or different tables for this. Some dummy example field names would be:

```
product_line^product_name
product_line^product_description
service_station^station_name
```

I've tested out hat (^) and pipe (|), and they don't work.

```
CREATE TABLE "my^test^table" ( "my^test^field" text )
```

(I used a GUI to build the tables, and I just now notice that you have to quote the names to even create the table/field.)

Here is what I have to do to query it:

```
SELECT "my^test^field" FROM "my^test^table"
```

... while I'd like to do:

```
SELECT my^test^field FROM my^test^table
```

... which is possible if I've used underscores (_):

```
SELECT my_test_field FROM my_test_table
```

**Are there any alternative delimiters other than underscore (_) which could work? Preferably a normal ASCII character which isn't alphanumeric.**

**Edit**: My best alternative at the moment is to use double underscore. But, I'd prefer something else.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Serious question... You're just making life more difficult for yourself...

Comment: What's wrong with the underscore? (I personally find the `^`  a **lot** more complicated to type and a it makes the words practically unreadable - at least for me)

Comment: @Phill It's very simple. I'm creating a view which is joining multiple tables where a lot of the column names are shared between the tables. I need a way to systematically distinguish between the fields. Adding a prefix solves this. The view is the final step before loading into a machine learning pipeline where the column names matter for further transformation and processing. Doing the join in postgres is more performant than doing it in python/pandas. Using a special delimiter for the prefix would make it easier to parse the field names in the ML pipeline.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Using an single underscore will make it impossible to process the column name automatically in the application layer. Sometimes the prefix has one underscore other times none, and other times two. Thus there is no easy way to extract the prefix. See the above answer for what the application layer does.

Comment: If you need "namespece" prefixes, then use schemas. If you need "meta data" about your columns, you could also store that in the column's comment.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Schema and column comments are not suitable for this use case. After I've joined the data into a wide view, ready for the ML pipeline, any schema naming convention is lost unless it is introduced as a column naming pattern. Furthermore, any column comment is lost during the export operation to the ML pipeline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use dollar signs. From [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

> SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (a-z, but also letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore (_). Subsequent characters in an identifier or key word can be letters, underscores, digits (0-9), or dollar signs ($). Note that dollar signs are not allowed in identifiers according to the letter of the SQL standard, so their use might render applications less portable.

I do not think it is a good idea.

I often use *thematic schemas*. Gather objects (tables, views, functions etc) belonging to specific submodels in separate schemas, e.g.:

```
inventory.items
inventory.get_items()
inventory.document_workflows
sale.contractors
sale.local_orders
etc
```

where `inventory` and `sale` are schemas.

Comment: Thank you. If it is a good idea should ultimately be judged on why I'm doing it like this. This isn't a transactional system, but part of a specialized data flow. The gist of it is that I'd like to leverage postgres' fast indexes and joining before passing the view data into a ML pipeline. The tables which are being joined have overlapping column names, something which needs to be resolved with something like a prefix. However, the prefix should be parsable in the pipeline. If I only use underscore there is no way to tell if `a` or `a_b` is the prefix in `a_b_c`.

Comment: I see. I think in this case dollar sign as a single char is practically the only option, with the ease of entering characters from the keyboard. However, you can also consider using double-underscores.

Comment: Thank you. I might just go with double underscore, as you suggest.

Answer (score 3):

Please, dont take this answer as advice for action. I think you are doing things that will make your life more complicated. But yet what you are looking for is doable. To get the list of accepted not quoted chars, I run:

```
t=# create schema s;
CREATE SCHEMA
Time: 0.931 ms
t=# do
$$
declare i record;
begin
for i in 1..255 loop
  begin
  execute format ('create table s.%s(i int)',chr(i)); --I deliberately don't use %I - so it would not add dblquotes for Identifier
  exception when others then NULL;
  end;
end loop;
end;
$$
;
DO
Time: 49.443 ms
t=# select tablename from pg_tables where tablename !~ '[aA-zZ]';
```

this will give you the list of characters accepted. Based on which you can experiment, eg:

```
t=# create table a©b (i int);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 2.920 ms
t=# select * from a©b;
 i
---
(0 rows)
```

or

```
t=# create table a­-b (i int);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 1.707 ms
t=# select * from a-­b;
 i
---
(0 rows)
```

Mind it is no hyphen (45), it is (173) one:

```
t=# select ascii('­-'),ascii('-');
 ascii | ascii
-------+-------
   173 |    45
(1 row)
```

So any of `÷, ® © ¤ £ ¡¦` and so on would do the trick. But now look at them and think - maybe you should solve different task?..

Comment: There are some really interesting ones, like `...` (the single character) or `»`. Though **most of them** might be there for an error. Only *a-z, but also letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters* supposed to be accepted, so relying on some of these might fall into the same category as `$`: *Note that dollar signs are not allowed in identifiers according to the letter of the SQL standard, so their use might render applications less portable.* -- BTW the `NULL;` statement is a valid *noop* statement, you don't have to do `PERFORM now();`

Comment: yes :) forgot to sweep up - `perform` made me look silly. well - with such answer won't look too smart anyway. anyway - thank you for your notice!

Comment: The set of these signs depends on local settings (in contrary to dollar sign).

Comment: @VaoTsun Thank you. I think using a delimiter is the right way to go. What I'm doing is the final step in joining multiple tables before a machine learning pipeline takes over. Unfortunately, some of these tables have identically named columns. Because postgres is a lot more performant with joining I want it to be done there, before entering the ML application pipeline. (1/2)

Comment: @VaoTsun However, the ML pipeline needs to be able to distinguish where each field comes from. A prefix solves this. I just need a way to split between the prefix and the original field name. A special character does a good job with this. Ultimately I've decided to use a view for this, as opposed to my original thought of using a table with DB level ETL. (2/2)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answers here I've decided not to use a different character as a prefix delimiter. I'm going with a double underscore (`__`), which is nicely parsable.

I should have been more clear on why I ultimately wanted this. The various comments I've left here explain it.

Here is an example which is pretty close to what we're probably ending at:

```
CREATE VIEW flat_data AS
SELECT 
    hub.id,
    idx_dly.ror_sd AS idx_dly__ror_sd,
    fx_dly.ror_sd AS fx_dly__ror_sd
FROM 
    hub
JOIN
    index_daily_movement AS idx_dly ON hub.id = idx_dly.hub_id
JOIN
    forex_daily_movement AS fx_dly ON hub.id = fx_dly.hub_id
...
```

In the application layer it is now possible to do things like

```
field_name = ... e.g. 'idx_dly__ror_sd'
table_abr, base_field_name = field_name.split('__')
```